# iOS Button not clickable during animation

Tags: ios, animation, sdk

When I added animation to my button using a category method, then I can't click that button, seems it is disabled:

```
[_compassCalibrateButton pulse:1.5 continuously:YES];
_compassCalibrateButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

I have a UIView category contatining this :

```
- (void)pulse:(float)secs continuously:(BOOL)continuously {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs/2 
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         // Fade out, but not completely
                         self.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:secs/2 
                                               delay:0.0 
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                          animations:^{
                                              // Fade in
                                              self.alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                                              if (continuously) {
                                                  [self pulse:secs continuously:continuously];
                                              }
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the doc

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are
>   disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to
>   interact with the views, include the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options
>   parameter.

So your code should be

```
- (void)pulse:(float)secs continuously:(BOOL)continuously {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs/2 
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         // Fade out, but not completely
                         self.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:secs/2 
                                               delay:0.0 
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                          animations:^{
                                              // Fade in
                                              self.alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                                              if (continuously) {
                                                  [self pulse:secs continuously:continuously];
                                              }
                                          }];
                     }];

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I tested on Swift 4

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        // Do Something
    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help you

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      for (UIButton *button in self.arrBtn)
      {
          if ([button.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
         {
        // This button was hit whilst moving - do something with it here
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
             NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
             break;
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are animating a `UIButton` to fade out after a while, e.g.:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:3.0 options:|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    self->btn.alpha = 0;
} completion:nil];
```

It will be unresponsive from the very start, regardless your 'delay', due to the final alpha. One way around this is something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    self->btn.alpha = 0.1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){self->btn.alpha = 0;}];
```