# Annotations are not clickable until animation ends

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, swift3, mapkit

As we all know, to move map markers we have to use this code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
     self.marker.coordinate = newCoordinate
})
```

but in this case, during all 10 seconds my annotation are not clickable!
they only became clickable on 11 second.

I know I can use Timer and calculate coordinates myself as in Google maps, but maybe you know better solution?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742321/ios-button-not-clickable-during-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to : options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(timeLeft), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations:  {
```

Format the code above, you get the idea.

[Taken from here where I answered similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907177/running-animation-on-tableviewcell-blocks-user-interaction/41907326#41907326)